# "Unexpected digit after hash token" requiring IFC file in React Native

Tags: react-native, three.js, expo, loader, ifc

I'm simply trying to perform a `require(./file.ifc)` into my application so I can run it with threejs and expo-gl. Although when I require it, I get this error:

```
error: SyntaxError: /Users/niltonsf/Desktop/Project/codes.nosync/prjs12/src/test2.ifc: Unexpected digit after hash token. (28:0)

  26 |
  27 | DATA;
> 28 | #1= IFCORGANIZATION($,'Autodesk Revit 2021 (ESP)',$,$,$);
     | ^
  29 | #5= IFCAPPLICATION(#1,'2021','Autodesk Revit 2021 (ESP)','Revit');
  30 | #6= IFCCARTESIANPOINT((0.,0.,0.));
```

How I'm attempting to load it:

```
import { IFCLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/IFCLoader';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';

export function Main() {
  const getUrl = async () => {
    const filePath = require('./test2.ifc') as any;
    const asset = Asset.fromModule(filePath);    
  };
```

My metro.config.js with I had to insert `.ifc` so I don't get an error when requiring it:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg', 'ifc', 'dwg', 'dxf'],
    },
  };
})();
```